# git in cmd wrongly uses cygdrive

Tags: git, cmd.exe

I'm on Windows 10 and installed Git `git version 2.19.1.windows.1`. I cd into a folder `D:\Webs\bildresize2` that's a git repo and call `git fetch`.
I get the error:

```
fatal: 'C:/Program Files/git/cygdrive/d/GIT/bildresize.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't understand why git tries to translate the path to `cygdrive` and breaks it. I find myself in a folder on drive `d:`, git however tries to do something in its own folder and then appends `cygdrive/d/GIT` that's completely wrong.

Is there a setting I can change?

Comment: Please add ALL the commands that you've typed.

Comment: I simply called `git fetch` nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Dumbest issue of them all.
The `.git/config` file has these lines

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = file:///cygdrive/d/GIT/bildresize.git
```

I created this repo in different environment than `cmd` and used `file` protocol as remote.

Comment: i guess if you had run process monitor on git.exe it might've picked up that it was reading the config file and that would've been a reminder to check it.. but anyhow, well spotted